# Why the ccsm has duplicated tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The Compiz Config Settings Manager or ccsm have two tags:

[compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compiz) used 1169 times

[ccsm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ccsm) used 25 times

Why don't include the `cssm` tag into the `compiz` one?

No one of both could be deleted?

Or no one can do anything while the users still use the `cssm` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager) is just a single tool of the entire compiz compositing manager. It's an optional tool, and a power user tool at that. Thereby, since tags are designed to make it easier to track questions users are interested in compiz developers probably don't want to follow ccsm questions, whereas power users may want to follow ccsm vs all compiz questions. By that comparison you could make arguments for having all desktop applications be tagged "ubuntu-desktop" (PS: Never ever use this tag, ever.) since you'll need a desktop and Ubuntu to run these applications.

It's not about taxonomy, it's about community :)

Comment: I noticed that I formulate the question wrong, I wanted to say: *the users with ccsm issues are using the Compiz tag*

Comment: @Lucio They were made synonyms a long time ago. I've undone this so they both exist as their own. As for questions being tagged with both, while it seems redundant it's not _that_ big of an issue. If better tags belong on the post then you can edit out the compiz tag or if the post requires other fixes then take the opportunity to remove the tag. Otherwise it's not worth just editing a post to remove that one tag.

Comment: I'm agree with you. Your information (*compiz developers probably don't want to follow ccsm questions*) is what I was looking for with this question :)